# Powershell unable to exact match folder full name

Tags: powershell, comparison-operators, get-childitem

I have a script to get all the files inside the folder by using powershell get-childitem command. I am using the pipeline with match parameter to filter the file name as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \\path\*  -recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match 'backup'}
```

Output:
[image]

Expectation Result:

> Only folder name exact match 'backup' will be in result, backup 2
>   should be not in the result.

Seem like the match parameter will behave alike 'backup*', Tried others comparison operators such as -ceq, -eq, -like, -contains and etc, but none of them working as intended, most of them return no result at all. What's the comparison operators should I use or is there other solution for this issue?

Comment: `-match` parameter doesn't do an exact match. It is a regex match. That is why you are getting backup 2 too.

You can use the `-eq` operator with the `BaseName` or only `Name` method. Something like this - `Get-ChildItem -Path \\path\*  -recurse | Where-Object {$_.BaseName -eq'backup'}`

Comment: Thanks. However `-eq` operator only support a single value right? I still using `-match` due to can input several values for filtering.

Comment: Yes correct, but you can use `-and` operator for several input values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-match` uses regex and checks if a string cointains it (indeed like `'*backup*'` ).
However the string you get from `$_.fullname` uses `\` to seperate folders. So we could check for `'\backup\'`. But since `-match` uses regex we need to escape the `\` with `\`:

```
...| Where-Object {$_.FullName -match '\\backup\\'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this with `$_.Name`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\path\\"  -recurse | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'backup'}
```

The `-eq` operator matches with the exact file name.

Answer (score 0):

If its the direct parentfolder you want to match you could just do that:

```
... | Where-Object {$_.Parent.Name -eq 'backup'}
```